# Word or phrase for "the call just ended"

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If we don't pick up a call,it just ends. So can "hang up" be used in this sense? I mean it's used with people.

Like:

> Mom: Hey! I thought my phone was ringing.
>
> I: It was but it just hung up.(no one picked it up and it ended like any call if no one picks it up.)

I guess the use of "hang up" isn't natural. So what will be actually be used in this context?

Comment: Sometimes the person on the other end hasn't hung up, but the call has *rolled over to voice mail*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hang up" is fine, but I would phrase it as "They hung up (before I could answer it)" The subject should be the person making the call, not the telephone.

I wouldn't say "the call ended" as in this situation the call hasn't begun.  You could say "the phone stopped ringing"

Comment: And @James K, can it be "the call just ended"(I didn't answer the call)

Comment: And @James K,will "the call ended " be more natural?